# Circumsision without mikvah

Tags: halacha, conversion-to-judaism

To my knowledge, when a male converts to Judaism, he must not only undergo Bris Milah but also must go to the mikvah. At what point during the process is he considered a full Jew? For instance, if he undergoes Bris Milah with the right intentions without going to the mikvah, is that a valid conversion, at least bedieved? Or vice versa - is he considered Jewish if he goes to the mikvah without getting a Bris Milah?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47437/discussion-between-donielf-and-mevaqesh).

Comment: For the fascinating case of Warder Cresson who was circumcised, but not yet immersed, and varying rabbinic views on his status, see http://seforim.blogspot.com/2014/02/rabbi-jacob-ettlinger-and-warder-cresson.html and Torat Rabbenu Shmuel Salant ztz"l (Vol 1 Siman #31).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortly after posting this question I saw that this was discussed in Geirim 1:6:

> גר שמל ולא טבל טבל ולא מל הכל הולך אחר המילה דברי ר״א. רע״א אף טבילה מעכבת.

R' Eliezer: Everything goes after the Milah. If he had a Milah, he's Jewish.
R' Akiva: Even tevilah blocks. Therefore, a geir needs both.

Since R' Akiva trumps everyone if not defending against more than one Tanna (R' Akiva al chaveiro v'lo chaveirav), we would pasken like him.

Indeed, the Gemara in Yevamos 46a quotes R' Yochanan, who holds like R' Akiva:

> דאמר ר׳ חייא בר אבא אמר ר׳ יוחנן לעולם אין גר עד שימול ויטבול וכיון דלא טביל עובד כוכבים הוא.
>   As R' Chiya bar Abba said in the name of R' Yochanan, a man can never be a convert until he has done Bris Milah and gone to the mikvah. Since [the man in question in that sugya] didn't go to the mikvah, he is still a non-Jew.

Later on the same amud a Braisa is quoted, in which R' Eliezer's opinion is held likewise by R' Yehoshua, with each of them bringing proofs respectively from the Avos and Imahos. The Chachamim argue, holding like R' Akiva:

> ת״ר גר שמל ולא טבל ר״א אומר הרי זה גר שכן מצינו באבותינו שמלו ולא טבלו טבל ולא מל ר׳ יהושע אומר הרי זה גר שכן מצינו באמהות שטבלו ולא מלו וחכמים אומרים טבל ולא מל מל ולא טבל אין גר עד שימול ויטבול

The Rambam (Issurei Biah 13:6) paskens like R' Akiva and the Chachamim:

> גר שמל ולא טבל או טבל ולא מל אינו גר עד שימול ויטבול

Likewise, the Tur (YD 268:1):

> גר שבא להתגייר אינו גר עד שימול ויטבול